# JQuery UI Datepicker visible

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want remove popup, make it static.

So that I can choose date without click at the field first.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

Comment: Refer this link http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: You can set display of css of datepicker to block

Comment: still not working. i try put display:block at css. then i try $('yourDatepicker').datepicker('show'); and it show but after i select date it hide.

Comment: actually i need to cr8 website like this http://www.ibilik.my/short_term_rentals/150496/brand-new-studio-for-rental  how to get code to show available date?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the datepicker to div not to input field then it will display as static

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker").datepicker();
});

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

reference:

[Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline)